# What is appropriate Linq Query for my tables?

Tags: c#, linq

I am using  C# ASP.NET Framework 4.5

Here is my table Structure

```
public class Product{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual List<ProductVariants> ProductVariants { get; set; } 
}

public class ProductVariants {
    public int ProductVariantsID { get; set; }
    public int ProductID { get; set; }

    public string FrontImage { get; set; }
    public string BackImage { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

---

What will be appropriate Linq query along displaying data in multiple pages ?  I want to display data as following format.

- Product 1, Name, Description
      - Front Image 1, Back Image 1, Price
- Product 2, Name, Description
      - Front Image 1, Back Image 1, Price

  ```
  - Front Image 2, Back Image 2, Price
  ```
- Product 3, Name, Description
      - Front Image 1, Back Image 1, Price

Please Help !!!

Comment: What is `Front Image 1`? There are many Font images?

Comment: To me, this looks like `SELECT [all columns here] FROM Table`.. you literally want everything returned as far as I can see..

Comment: In product3, why should there be Front Image1? I couldn't understand the logic behind it. Please explain a bit more

Comment: Assuming you want a Linq2EF query. Pretty much just `context.Product.Include(x => x.ProductVariants).ToList()`. The "difficult" part is getting ASP.Net to display the Products in the way you want...

Comment: Dear Aron.  yes I want Linq 2 EF. I understand a bit your meaning from  
     context.Product.Include(x => x.ProductVariants).ToList()
Can you elaborate little more ..

is it like 

products = context.Product.Include(x => x.ProductVariants).ToList()

and then how will use to display it on multiple pages ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this way :

```
var q =
    from pv in ProductVariants
    join p in Product on pv.ProductID equals p.ProductID
    select new { //... };

foreach (var v in q)
{
    Console.WriteLine(v.Name + ", " + v.Description);
    Console.WriteLine(v.FrontImage + ", " + v.BackImage+ ", " +v.Price);
}
```